# How to Exit tty1 mode into Gui mode in ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: command-line, dual-boot

I'm using the Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS and automatic it's showing me black screen and work only in terminal mode.It ask me to login in terminal mode.
So how can I go back in GUI mode.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgTeD.jpg)

Comment: ubuntu the GUI can be found with Ctrl+Alt+F2.

Comment: Please apply all security fixes, as 20.04.5 implies you're behind on security fixes (*or you didn't check & provided inaccurate information*).  This [link](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/) will show the ISO release date for 20.04.6, but installed systems received that upgrade & reported as 20.04.6 in the week before the ISO release.